# How do I reference files with brackets in the name

Tags: powershell

Create a file called Valid[File].txt and stick some text in it.  Start powershell and go to the directory.

```
gc Valid[File].txt
```

should display the value in the file.  It returns blank.  If you use tab auto-completion it escapes the name:

```
gc 'Valid[File].txt'
```

but still returns nothing.

How do I reference files with brackets in their names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the key was `-literalpath`.  For details see [this technet article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/pstips/jun08/pstip0620.mspx)

Comment: Ouch.  It's easier to install Cygwin!

Comment: @jonathan It may be easier, but on the Windows platform, PowerShell has more opportunities and "power".

Comment: There are known bugs with handling of brackets in filenames. It'll be fixed in v2.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enclose it in quotation marks: gc "Valid[File].txt"